# Vertical positioning of text in UITabBar changes when multitasking size changes - how to correct?

Tags: text, layout, positioning, uitabbar, ipados

I'm adding a UITabBarController to my app.

At the same time I'm now supporting multitasking on iPad.

When in fullscreen the text in the UITabBar is vertically positioned just above centre Y in the Tab Bar (this is done by the framework). However, with zero custom code, when the user puts the app into a multitasking mode i.e. split 2/3 or 1/3, then the vertical positioning of the text in the Tab Bar changes so it's below centre Y vertically.

This is happening by default from the framework, I have no subclass of UITabBar and my UITabBarController subclass isn't doing anything to the 'self.tabbar'...

How can I fix what's happening in the framework because it looks awful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]